# How to get and return user input in the same method on Android

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

(I know this question has been asked in many different flavors, thanks for considering the specifics of my situation).

I am implementing a 3rd party library.  One of the methods requires user input, and the **return value of this method needs to be the user's response**.  Specifically, this method needs to pop up an alert dialog.  The user will have 3 buttons to choose from and the return value of this method must be an int identifying the button the user clicked.

The only way I've gotten this working is by calling this alert method from an AsyncTask and from there calling runOnUIThread to pop up the alert and then wait for the response.  Where I'm stuck is the case where this alert method is being called from the UI thread.  Is there a similar work around to wait on a response in this case?

This is what my code currently looks like... as long as this method is called from an AsyncTask I'm good to go.  BUT, I need to be able to call it from the UI thread.

```
public int getInput(final Object [] args)
{
    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            buildDialog(args).show();
        }
    });

    try
    {
        synchronized(this)
        {
            wait();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    return m_Result;
}

public void setRetValue(int result)
{
    m_Result = result;
    synchronized(this)
    {
        notify();
    }
}
```

(setRetValue gets called from onClick in the OnClickListeners of the buttons in the dialog.)

Comment: Example code please of what you have done so far?